# How R graphs regressions with a factor IV

Tags: r, graphics, regression

I usually use SAS but I trying to use R more. I am trying to show how categorizing a continuous independent variable messes up regressions. So I created some data:

```
set.seed(1234) #sets a seed.  It is good to use the same seed all the time.

x <- rnorm(100)  #X is now normally distributed with mean 0 and sd 1, N - 100
y <- 3*x + rnorm(100,0,10) #Y is related to x, but with some noise
x2 <- cut(x, 2) #Cuts x into 2 parts
```

then I ran a regression on x2:

```
m2 <- lm(y~as.factor(x2)) #A model with the cut variable
summary(m2)
```

and the summary was what I expected: A coefficient for the intercept and one for the dummy variable:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ as.factor(x2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-30.4646  -6.5614   0.4409   5.4936  29.6696 

Coefficients:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)                 -1.403      1.290  -1.088   0.2795  
as.factor(x2)(0.102,2.55]    4.075      2.245   1.815   0.0726 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 10.56 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.03253,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02265 
F-statistic: 3.295 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.07257
```

But when I graphed x vs. y and added a line for the regression from m2, the line was smooth - I would have expected a jump where x2 goes from 0 to 1.

```
plot(x,y)
abline(reg = m2)
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing something basic?

Comment: you're not doing it wrong, it is just that *"the first 2 values are taken to be the intercept and slope."* (from `?abline`). As the indedendent is a factor variable, you could just use `h=` to draw the horizontal lines `abline(h=cumsum(coef(m2)))`;  You could avoid the `cumsum` by removing the intercept in `lm`.

Comment: Thanks.  If you post that as an answer, I will accept it.